# ¿Uso de "confligir" fuera de Puerto Rico?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, diferencias-regionales, españa, puerto-rico

Hace apenas 5 minutos estaba escribiendo un informe y tenía que indicar que una serie de cambios entraban en conflicto con otros cambios previos. Y lo primero que me ha venido a la cabeza ha sido lo siguiente:

> Habrá que hacer algunas adaptaciones menores (hay otros cambios que **confligen** con estos).

Lo puse de manera natural: de *conflicto*, *confligir*. Sonaba bien.

Pero el corrector ortográfico me lo ha subrayado en rojo y ya me ha entrado la duda, así que me he ido al DLE:

> **[confligir](http://dle.rae.es/?w=confligir)**.
>
> 1. intr. *P. Rico*. Entrar en conflicto.

¡Uf, menos mal! Existe. Mejor, porque ya he mandado el informe...
Pero lo cierto es que el DLE marca el verbo como usado solamente en Puerto Rico. Ante lo cual, pregunto:

**¿Se usa *confligir* en España como verbo para indicar "entrar en conflicto"?

¿Y en otros países que no sean Puerto Rico?**

Comment: Yo jamás lo he escuchado y no estoy seguro de si hubiera podido deducir su significado si veo la palabra sin contexto.

Comment: Soy de México y no recuerdo haber visto o escuchado esa palabra. "Entrar en conflicto" es más común.

Comment: En casi medio siglo de hablar español (de Argentina), nunca escuché o leí esa palabra. Ni siquiera me fue obvio qué podría querer decir cuando vi la palabra en el título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues va a ser que no. He buscado `conflig*` en el CORDE, y el resultado es que todos los casos son de textos en latín. El único que está en español es este:

> *Como teseo por suerte fuesse enbiado a ser confligido con el minotauro de athenas en creta en su nauio por mandado de egeo Rey de athenas puso uela negra & mando asus conpañeros [...].*
>
> Alfonso Gómez de Zamora, "Morales de Ovidio", a 1452 (España).

No he podido saber qué sentido tiene *confligido* en ese texto, dado que no aparece *confligir* en ningún diccionario del NTLLE.

Una búsqueda similar en el CREA arroja 7 casos en 4 documentos, todos en Puerto Rico. De aquí se puede desprender que, efectivamente, es un verbo usado exclusivamente allí. Lo cual no quita para que tu documento sea un buen punto de partida para empezar a difundir la palabra por España...